# Android - How to read Manufacturing data from Advertising data on Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to implement an Android app that will connect to the Bluetooth LE device.

The device has an On/Off (ready-to-pair/not-ready-to-pair) switch that App should verify before connecting to it. The only way to know is to read the Manufacturing data from Advertising data using onLeScan.

When I try to get the byte[] scanRecord, it shows something like *02 01 06 03 02 15 18 02 FF 30 08 09 47 4D 32 38 32 36 49 05 12 50 00 20 03 02 0A 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00*.

Now I want to get the value like **'mfgdata & 0x04'** that means ready-to-pair but I really dont know whats the next step. Sorry for this noob question. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. For test, try http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx
Yours hex had been converted to GM2826IP